# Bootstrap is not working on mobile devices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mysite/css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="mysite/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="mysite/js/jquery-ui.js"></script></head><body><nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197" role = "navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" 
     data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#example-navbar-collapse">
     <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
     <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
     <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="mysite/Dashboard.php"><img src='mysite/img/logo43.png'></a>
</div>
<div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "example-navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Stock
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="mysite/update.php">Change Stock</a></li>          <li><a href="mysite/search.php">Stock Details</a></li>          <li><a href="mysite/totalstock.php">Total Stock</a></li>          <li><a href="mysite/report.php">Item Movement</a></li>        </ul>
  </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Add
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="mysite/add/addItem.php">Add Item</a></li>          <li><a href="mysite/add/addBrands.php">Add Brand</a></li>          <li><a href="mysite/add/addCategory.php">Add Category</a></li>          <li><a href="mysite/add/addUser.php">Add User</a></li>        </ul>
  </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">All Operations
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="mysite/view/viewStock.php">All Items</a></li>            <li><a href="mysite/view/viewBrand.php">All Brands</a></li>          <li><a href="mysite/view/viewCategory.php">All Categories</a></li>          <li><a href="mysite/view/viewUser.php">All Users</a></li>        </ul>
  </li>
      <li><a href="mysite/dailyreport.php">Daily Report</a></li>    </ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Welcome burhantec</a></li>
  <li><a href="mysite/logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav><div class='alert alert-success'><strong>Hello ! </strong>Welcome to Mysite Technology Computer Company, It is a great honour to have you in our team.</div>
<script src="mysite/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="mysite/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
   body {
     background: rgba(38, 102, 157, 0.87);
     color: white;
   }
   .td-center{
    text-align: center;
   }
   .th-center{
        text-align: center;
   }
   input{
    color: black;
   }
   input.userlogin{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    outline: 0;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
    transition-duration: 0.25s;
    font-weight: 300;
    }
    input.userlogin:focus{
        left: -10%;
        position: relative;
        width: 120%;
    }
    .btnlogin{
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        outline: 0;
        border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
        width: 250px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: white;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
        transition-duration: 0.25s;
        font-weight: 300;
        background-color: white;
        color: rgba(38, 102, 157, 0.87);
    }
    .btnlogin:hover{
        color: white;
        background-color: rgba(38, 102, 157, 0.87);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .navbar-inverse {
        background-color: #002E56;

    }
    .affix {
          top: 0;
          width: 100%;
          z-index: 99;
      }

      .affix + .container-fluid {
          padding-top: 70px;
      }
      th.td-center{
        background-color: #F5AC56;
      }
      .export-message{
        position: absolute;
        top: 120px;
        right: 120px;
      }
      .modal-content {
        background-color: #5f7a92;
      }
      .mg-left{
        margin-left:20px;
      }
      .mg-top{
        margin-top: 20px;
      }
      .mg-bottom{
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).delay(200).fadeIn(200);
    }, function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(200);
    });
    </script>
    </body></html>
```

It is not unfortunately responsive on my mobile & Desktop Google Chrome when tried mobile view, But when I tried mobile view on desktop mozilla firefox It is working..

I am using Bootstrap Jquery UI for this web app

Comment: Could you tell us what it is that doesn't work? Is it the whole website? The responsive part of the website?
If it is the responsive part of the website the reason is that you don't make use of the bootstrap grid system.

Comment: Responsive part not working but i am using bootstrap navbar which automatically changes to '3 horizontal lines' icon and when clicking it, shows sub menu, Other than this I have only one line to show 'welcome to mysite...' that's also I am using as an alert , I don't think i need grid systems at all

Comment: I can't see the meta for the viewport, which causes the responsive to trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following line between the `<head></head>` tags:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

This should help, if you also want to make the content of your website responsive. Have a look at the bootstrap grid system like I suggested before.

Comment: Thanks Frank for your help